# Simple Location API This method must return a result of type boolean

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have following problem:
I use BB Eclipse plugin as my IDE and recently I have imported new project easing use of location API on BlackBerry [Simple Location API](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Simple-Location-API/ta-p/1145951).

I don't know why but in SimpleLocationProvider class in line [593](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Simple%20Location%20API/src/rimx/location/simplelocation/SimpleLocationProvider.java#L593) (which is a comment line) I am getting error:

*This method must return a result of type boolean*

I am confused a little, because this is downloaded example and method before comment returns *BlackBerryLocation* and method after comment does not return anything. Here is part of a print screen from my Eclipse
[image]

Comment: did you try to clean your project via project--> clean?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but actually it helped to remove all `//#ifdef` and `//#endif`

Comment: @MichK, did you solve your own problem?  If so, please either remove the question, or post the solution as an answer, and **accept** it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by removing all lines containing `//#ifdef` and `//#endif`.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're using 5.0 SDK and trying to compile 6.0 example

Comment: @EugenMartynov thanks for suggestion but actually I use 7.1 SDK. And I also removed code which was specific for 5.0 example and left only code for 6.0 example, and in that "state" my example application didn't compile. But after removing (only) lines with `//#ifdef` and `//#endif` (not code between them) everything started to work.